# Unable to save within a Sequelize hook

Tags: sequelize.js, bcrypt

I'm using bcrypt-nodejs with Sequelize. I'm trying to hash a guest's password before the guest object is persisted to the database, but can't figure out why this does not save to my database:

```
Guest.beforeCreate(function(guest) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(error, salt) {
    if (error) { return error }
    bcrypt.hash(guest.password, salt, null, function(error, hash) {
      if (error) { return error }
      guest.password = hash;
    })
  })
});
```

However, this does:

```
Guest.beforeCreate(function(guest) {
  guest.password = "something";
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that a .save() method is provided by Sequelize.

This now works and persists to the database:

```
Guest.beforeCreate(function(guest) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(error, salt) {
    if (error) { return error }
    bcrypt.hash(guest.password, salt, null, function(error, hash) {
      if (error) { return error }
      guest.password = hash;
      guest.save(); // Added this line to get it to save.
    })
  })
});
```